# How do you format balances with the Polkadot JS API?

Tags: substrate, polkadot-js

I would like to get the balance of a user formatted using the base unit of the Substrate chain.

When I use `toHuman()`, I get an opinionated formatting which includes a prefix like so:

```
let account = await api.query.system.account("EGVQCe73TpFyAZx5uKfE1222XfkT3BSKozjgcqzLBnc5eYo");
account.data.free.toHuman()
```

> 2.8320 kKSM

While `toNumber()` returns the value without any units at all:

```
account.data.free.toNumber()
```

> 2832057009447293

How do I get this value with just the base units using the Polkadot JS API?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to query the chain for the `chainDecimals`, which will tell you how many places into the raw value you should place the decimal:

```
api.registry.chainDecimals
```

> 12

You can either directly parse the number by dividing by 10<sup>chainDecimals</sup>, or you can use the Polkadot JS utility function `formatBalance` to help you format this a bit more easily:

```
formatBalance(
    accountData.data.free,
    { withSi: false, forceUnit: '-' },
    chainDecimals
);
```

> 2,832.057

I ended up making a utility function like this:

```
function toUnit(balance, decimals) {
    base = new BN(10).pow(new BN(decimals));
    dm = new BN(balance).divmod(base);
    return parseFloat(dm.div.toString() + "." + dm.mod.toString())
}
```

Comment: I don't think `"."+ dm.mod.toString()` works because mod won't print leading zeroes (they're insignificant digits as an integer).

`formatBalance` looks useful in my case, although I'm having a hard time finding documentation for it (this post is actually the first search hit for "polkadotjs formatBalance").

The code for `formatBalance` can be found here: https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/blob/master/packages/util/src/format/formatBalance.ts

Comment: Currently `chainDecimals` is set using `decimals` in the options object passed to `formatBalance`